# Bootstrap-table and rails Not able to DESTROY Entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I have the bootstrap-table plugin working and the table displays great.  However I am trying to have an edit button and a delete button.  I can get the edit button to work.  However, I can't figure out how to send a destroy through my JS I have.  Also, I have one other problem.  When the page loads initially, the JSON table does not load.  I have to refresh the page to get a full table.  Any thoughts?

index.html.erb:

```
    <div id="custom-toolbar">
      <%= link_to new_weight_tracker_path, :class => "btn btn-default", :remote => true, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#addMeasurement", 'aria-label' => "Add New Measurement" do %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><% end %>
</div>
<table id="table-pagination" data-toggle="table" data-url="/weight_trackers.json" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#custom-toolbar" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-height="600" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="user_date" data-show-export="true" data-sort-order="desc" data-export-types="['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'excel']" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="weight" data-sortable="true" data-align="right">Weight:</th>
      <th data-field="waist" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="right">Waist:</th>
      <th data-field="wrist" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="right">Wrist:</th>
      <th data-field="hip" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="right">Hip:</th>
      <th data-field="forearm" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="right">Forearm:</th>
      <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true" data-visible="false" data-align="left">Note:</th>
      <th data-field="user_date" data-sortable="true" data-align="right">Date:</th>
      <th class="nopadding" data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents" data-align="center" data-valign="center" data-halign="center"></th>
      <th class="nopadding" data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter2" data-events="operateEvents" data-align="center" data-valign="center" data-halign="center"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<br /> <br />
<!-- End JSON Table -->
```

application.js:

```
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [
        '<a class="edit ml10 btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>',
        '</a>'
    ].join('');
}

function operateFormatter2(value, row, index) {
    return [
        '<a class="remove ml10 btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Delete">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>',
        '</a>'
    ].join('');
}

window.operateEvents = {
    'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
        document.location.href='/weight_trackers/' + row.id + '/edit'

        console.log(value, row, index);
    },
    'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('Are you sure you want to delete entry for ' + row.created_at);
        document.location.href='/weight_trackers/' + row.id
        console.log(value, row, index);
    }
};
```

weight_tracker_controller.rb destroy method:

```
  def destroy
  @weight_tracker.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Measurement Deleted"
  respond_with(@weight_tracker)
  end
```

How can I get the click .remove to delete the entry?  And the dtaa to load automatically when page loads initially.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best way.  But I have added the following to my application.js calls for delete.  And it is working.

```
function operateFormatter2(value, row, index) {
    return [
        '<a class="remove ml10 btn btn-default" data-method="delete" href="/weight_trackers/' + row.id + '" title="Delete">',
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>',
        '</a>'
    ].join('');
}

    'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('Are you sure you want to delete entry for ' + row.created_at);
        document.location.href='/weight_trackers'
        console.log(value, row, index);
    }
};
```